# Manager unable to edit the Task which he has created in salesforce insufficient privileges?

Tags: tasks

In the Prod org. I have Role Hierarchy based on the Category and Sub-Category. 5 Category and Subcategory combinations, so 5 different Managers and Agents under it.

When Case is submitted successfully, Queue becomes owner of the Case and Queue member manager is taking the Ownership of the Case. Now Manager becomes owner, Queue member lose the access.

Now Manager creates the Task and assignee of the task is Employee. When Manager tries to create the task, he gets  insufficient privileges?

Comment: In the manager's profile, is Create checked under Task?

Comment: Agent is Owner on the Case, create Task against manager, was able to create it, but when trying to edit it .. facing error insufficient privileges?